# Apache 2.2 wont start on Server 2012 R2

Tags: apache-http-server

This is the error message I get, but `netstat` investigation reveals port `4343` is not being utilized.

```
[Fri Apr 06 11:44:21 2018] [warn] module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Apr 06 11:44:21 2018] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 4343, the first has precedence
(OS 10048) Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:4343
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably forgot the `NameVirtualHost` directive, it is needed before Apache 2.3

Answer (score 0):

As @patrick-mevzek states, you may wish to ensure that you have a [NameVirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) directive at the start of your name-based virtual host declarations e.g.:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

This declaration has been removed from current versions of Apache, but was necessary in Apache 2.2 and earlier.